# Applying UserForm List box Selections to selected cell

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

i have a patient list and i have used a listbox userform in order to select multiple diagnosis codes. I am only able to apply that listbox to the first cell, a2. regardless where i click in that column, i am unable to get the diganosis codes for the next patient to fall into the next row in that diganosis column. When i make a selection, they are returning back to cell a2, regardless of where i am selecting. The code i currently have is below. Can someone please help?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

myVar = ""

For x = 0 To Me.LLBXMedHist.ListCount - 1
     If Me.LLBXMedHist.Selected(x) Then
         If myVar = "" Then
              myVar = Me.LLBXMedHist.List(x, 0)
         Else
              myVar = myVar & "," & Me.LLBXMedHist.List(x, 0)
         End If
     End If
Next x

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2") = myVar

End Sub
```

Comment: The last line has a hard-coded A2 - you need to find the first blank cell in column A.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am very new to this, so excuse my ignorance; if i remove the "2" from A2 for the range, and select another row in column a to input the data,  it is giving me an error message. How should i remove the hard stop A2 and allow the user to be able to select any row in this column to select the diagnosis codes and input into that specific cell? (thanks for your help in advance)

Comment: So you want the user to select a cell in column A and put `myVar` into that?

Comment: I found this code to use for my list box in order to add a comma in between the selections. Thats the only reason i wanted to use this code. If i need to remove myVar, thats perfectly fine, i just want to make sure i can still do the  multiple selections and place commas in between each selection from the list box. (Im sorry im so new to this)